# Angular: How can I filter an object-Array with multiple conditions

Tags: arrays, angular, filtering

I have an object-array like this:

```
myObjectArray = [
 {name:'John', label:'ab', isActive: false},
 {name:'Sara', label:'bb', isActive: false},
 {name:'John', label:'cb', isActive: false},
 {name:'Nicole', label:'eb', isActive: true},
 {name:'Nicole', label:'eb', isActive: true},
 {name:'Nicole', label:'eb', isActive: true},
 {name:'Nicole', label:'eb', isActive: true},
 {name:'Sara', label:'fb', isActive: false},
 {name:'Thomas', label:'gb', isActive: false},
 {name:'Holly', label:'gb', isActive: true},
 {name:'Nicole', label:'hb', isActive: true},
 {name:'Nicole', label:'eb', isActive: true},
 {name:'Sara', label:'ib', isActive: false}
]
```

How can i filter this array like this to get this array:

```
myObjectArray = [
 {name:'John', label:'ab', isActive: false},
 {name:'Sara', label:'bb', isActive: false},
 {name:'Nicole', label:'eb', isActive: true},
 {name:'Thomas', label:'gb', isActive: false},
 {name:'Holly', label:'gb', isActive: true},
]
```

How can I filter duplicates with "find" in first array to get the scond array. Nicole occurs multiple times in the array. However, it must be preserved because isActive == true. Thanks.

**Update:**
I need all objects in the first array only once when isAktive == false. But I also need all objects that are isActive == true, no matter how many times they occur. Thanks.

Comment: Hey Lowterm. What exactly is the criteria? Find every name that is in a particular group? etc.

Comment: first of all your array is not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use filter on your object array with condition of

remove duplicates by comparing their name for isActive = false

or

allow duplicates for isActive = true

```js
const result = [
 {name:'John', label:'ab', isActive: false},
 {name:'Sara', label:'bb', isActive: false},
 {name:'John', label:'cb', isActive: false},
 {name:'Nicole', label:'eb', isActive: true},
 {name:'Sara', label:'fb', isActive: false},
 {name:'Thomas', label:'gb', isActive: false},
 {name:'Nicole', label:'hb', isActive: true},
 {name:'Sara', label:'ib', isActive: false}
].filter((value, index, self) =>
  index === self.findIndex((t) => (
    !t.isActive && t.name === value.name
  )) || value.isActive
)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: This is a fantastic solution. Unfortunately it does not bring me the desired result. Sometimes I have multiple objects with the same name and with isActive = true. These should be reduced to one entry if they occur several times in a row. This entry must be completely deleted if there is another object with a different name and isActive = true. Is this possible?